# How to request camera and location permission in android native sdk?(C++)

Tags: android-ndk, ndk-build

I've searched all over the web but cannot find anything related to permissions. Is it even doable in native C++? How do I do it? I am completely stuck.

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no C++ api to request app permissions.
You can use a callback from native to Java (via JNI) and ask for permissions in Java.